# file_get_contents() fails on specific urls with: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429

Tags: php, http-status-code-429

I am trying to use the Steam API but whenever I use a file_get_contents() with the Steam Community URL I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=578080&market_hash_name=Gas%20Mask): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429
```

If I use file_get_contents() on Google.com, for example, it returns the page without an error. I have tried to use curl which just returns random characters. Here is the code I used:

```
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=578080&market_hash_name=Gas%20Mask"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Result:

```
��+��O��%
```

Comment: Have you tried use curl instead file_get_contents?

Comment: When I use curl it returns: ��+��O��%.

Comment: update your question with the codes what you have tried

Comment: You problably got authentication error(s) from steam.

Comment: There is some problem with your server config I think. What kind of server /environment do you use? I just tried these codes on my servers, they works well

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6 if that may be a problem? It's strange because I can successfully use file_get_contents(''http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/".$steamid."/578080/2?l=english);

Comment: `HTTP/1.0 429 Too Many Requests`, You're probably temporarily banned from requesting any pages on that server. The *strange characters* are `gzip` encoded, you can use `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_ENCODING, "");` to decode them.

Answer (score 2):

My domain was temporarily banned from making requests to the URL. I tested the code on another server and it worked.